# Leer un .CSV en python con partidas de ajedrez

Tags: python, json, base-de-datos, windows, csv

Lo que tengo es un dataframe con estas columnas:

- headers (que contiene en formato JSON la información sobre cada partida),
- moves (que contiene la información sobre los movimientos efectuados en la
  partida),
- Nivel de las blancas, Nivel de las negras, ECO (código de la
  apertura), Nombre de la partida y Resultado de la partida.

La variable "headers" contiene entradas como esta:

```
**{'_tag_roster': {'Event': 'Rated Blitz game', 'Site': '?', 'Date':
'2022.03.12', 'Round': '-', 'White': 'Graukater', 'Black':
'YaYestGrut', 'Result': '1-0'}, '_others': {'LichessURL':
'https://lichess.org/Aq26yCEX', 'WhiteElo': '2611', 'BlackElo':
'2563', 'ECO': 'A04', 'Opening': 'Zukertort Opening: Dutch Variation',
'TimeControl': '180+0', 'UTCDate': '2022.03.12', 'UTCTime':
'18:12:59', 'Termination': 'Time forfeit', 'WhiteRatingDiff': '+5',
'BlackRatingDiff': '-5'}}**
```

Pero no tengo ni idea de como sacar de ahí la información referente al tipo de partida (donde aparece ('Event') y del tiempo 'TimeControl'. He probado cosas como un diccionario, pd.sjon_normalize() etc y nada.

Os dejo una captura de lo que tengo:

https://ibb.co/VHpHR9j
https://ibb.co/F5WpsGD

Comment: Recuerda colocar siempre un [repro] de lo que tienes hasta el momento _como texto, con formato_, sin apuntar a enlaces externos. Ten presente que parte esencial de la pregunta se perderá si los enlaces llegan a caer más adelante. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Me he fijado que en el dataframe se usa comillas simples (') en vez de las dobles comillas (") lo cual aunque compile bien en JS, incumple el standard JSON.

Es por este motivo que deberías reemplazar todas las comillas del texto antes de decodificar el JSON. Este sería un ejemplo funcional:

```
import json

headers = "{'_tag_roster': {'Event': 'Rated Blitz game', 'Site': '?', 'Date': '2022.03.12', 'Round': '-', 'White': 'Graukater', 'Black': 'YaYestGrut', 'Result': '1-0'}, '_others': {'LichessURL': 'https://lichess.org/Aq26yCEX', 'WhiteElo': '2611', 'BlackElo': '2563', 'ECO': 'A04', 'Opening': 'Zukertort Opening: Dutch Variation', 'TimeControl': '180+0', 'UTCDate': '2022.03.12', 'UTCTime': '18:12:59', 'Termination': 'Time forfeit', 'WhiteRatingDiff': '+5', 'BlackRatingDiff': '-5'}}"

h = json.loads(headers.replace('\'','"'))
print(h['_tag_roster']['Event'])
print(h['_others']['TimeControl'])
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Si hago x = games['headers'] y luego hago z = str(x[0]) (necesita ser string) seguido de tu código aplicado a z me funciona. ¿Sabes cómo hacerlo para todas y cada una de las entradas de games['headers']?

Comment: ¿Que te gustaría conseguir exactamente?

Comment: Tengo 366.000 datos como los que he puesto antes y para cada uno de ellos tengo que sacarle el valor de la variable Event y la variable TimeControl

Comment: reemplaza la linea donde seteo headers por: `for headers in games['headers']:` y añade identación a las 3 ultimas lineas para que formen parte de ese nuevo bucle for. Ahi lo tienes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tu columna realmente no es un JSON (texto plano, que aquí seria una cadena de texto, `str`) sino que seria un JSON ya parseado y convertido a estructuras de datos de Python, un diccionario en este caso.

Partiendo de un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import pandas as pd

games = pd.DataFrame({
    "headers": [
        {
            '_tag_roster': {'Event': 'Rated Blitz game'},
            '_others': {'TimeControl': '180+0'}
        },
        {
            '_tag_roster': {'Event': 'Rated Rapid game'},
            '_others': {'TimeControl': '153+0'}
        }
    ]
})
```

---

```
>>> games
                                             headers
0  {'_tag_roster': {'Event': 'Rated Blitz game'},...
1  {'_tag_roster': {'Event': 'Rated Rapid game'},...
```

Para obtener el valor de las claves que quieres en cada fila tienes varias opciones.

### Usar `pandas.Series.str`

La primera es usar `pandas.Series.str`. Este método esta pensado para ser usado con columnas de tipo `str`, no obstante funcionará también con un diccionario. Este uso no está documentado, por lo que yo lo considero más un detalle de implementación que podría dejar de funcionar en futuras versiones:

```
>>> games["headers"].str["_tag_roster"].str["Event"]

0    Rated Blitz game
1    Rated Rapid game
Name: headers, dtype: object
```

esto retorna una serie con el valor de la clave para cada fila. Si quieres agregar ambas claves a nuevas columnas en tu Dataframe puedes hacer:

```
games["Event"] = games["headers"].str["_tag_roster"].str["Event"]
games["TimeControl"] = game["headers"].str["_others"].str["TimeControl"]
```

### Usar `pandas.Series.map`

```
>>> games["headers"].map(lambda h: (h["_tag_roster"]["Event"]))

0    Rated Blitz game
1    Rated Rapid game
Name: headers, dtype: object
```

De nuevo, si quieres asignar los valores a nuevas columnas puedes hacer:

```
games["Event"] = games["headers"].map(lambda h: h["_tag_roster"]["Event"])
games["TimeControl"] = games["headers"].map(lambda h: h["_others"]["TimeControl"])
```

Tanto usando `str` como `map` el resultado seria:

```
>>> games
                                         headers             Event 

TimeControl
0  {'_tag_roster': {'Event': 'Rated Blitz game'},...  Rated Blitz game       180+0
1  {'_tag_roster': {'Event': 'Rated Rapid game'},...  Rated Rapid game       153+0
```

### Usar [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

Si vas a hacer esto con muchas o todas las claves del diccionario mejor deshacerse de el y generar un DataFrame a partir de la columna, lo que facilitará el procesado posterior y mejorara la eficiencia al facilitar la vectorización de operaciones.

```
norm_headers = pd.json_normalize(games["headers"])
```

---

```
>>> norm_headers
  _tag_roster.Event _others.TimeControl
0  Rated Blitz game               180+0
1  Rated Rapid game               153+0

>>> norm_headers["_tag_roster.Event"]
0    Rated Blitz game
1    Rated Rapid game
Name: _tag_roster.Event, dtype: object

>>> norm_headers["_others.TimeControl"]
0    180+0
1    153+0
Name: _others.TimeControl, dtype: object
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya me funciona! Te debo una cerveza

Comment: @Aston no ignores los comentarios :) Además, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta si en verdad te ha sido útil. De nuevo: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.